# How to get the returned value of a function called from settimeout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, liveagent

I have live agent set up and I am trying to set an alert on the agent side when a customer does not reply to his messages after a certain interval of time

Here is how I am trying to achieve (All these are in the js helper,being delegated from the js controller)

1)Declared A global variable  globalvariable1 which keeps track of its changed value

2. Used an onAgentMessageSend component which fires when an Agent chats

   ```
   onAgentMessageSend : function(cmp,recordId,content,name,type,timestamp){
   if(type=='Agent')
      {
          var self = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
          var returnedType=self.checkMessageSenderAndResetCounter(cmp);
         }, 5000);           

          if(returnedType=='Default Value')
          {alert('Unresponsive Customer');}
          else{
          console.log('customer responded hence reset');
          globalvariable1= 'Default Value'}}
          else{
           console.log('Do nothing');}},
   ```

3)A function to  change  the global value as and when coming from Agent or Customer

```
  checkMessageSenderAndResetCounter: function(cmp) {
 
 console.log('the current value of globalvarable'+this.globalvariable1);
 return this.globalvariable1;},
```

4. A method which is fired when a customer messages

   ```
    onNewMessageFromEndUser : function(cmp,recordId,content,name,type,timestamp){

        this.globalvariable1='Customer';},
   ```

Summing up,what i am trying to achieve here is once the agent chats,a timer is set for lets say 5 seconds,within that time frame if a customer replies the global variable changes and it continues,in case there is no reply from the customer end,the global variable is still a default value ,then it rasies an alert indicating that there is an unanswered question .
But the result from the Settimeout is not achieveable,could you please help out here for any other way to acheive this,or rectify this itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous code happens asynchronously. This means that other code in the direct code path will execute first, and then the asynchronous code will then execute. Notice in your code how the `var` is one function, but you try to use it in another? That's a sign that you're doing something wrong. Instead, you need a callback somehow. In modern code, you'd use a Promise:

```
if (type == 'Agent') {
    var self = this;
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function () {
                resolve(self.checkMessageSenderAndResetCounter(cmp));
            }), 5000
        );
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result == 'Default Value') {
            alert('Unresponsive Customer');
        } else {
            console.log('customer responded hence reset');
            globalvariable1 = 'Default Value';
        }
    });
}
```

A Promise does whatever is inside, then resolves to the then function (or catch, if there's an error, but I've omitted that here). Note also the use of $A.getCallback. This ensures that Aura is active and the component can be updated and events fired, if necessary. It's a good habit to use this function, even if you don't immediately need it.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox ,the thing is,this is immdiately firing the alert and showing as soon as the agent puts in a message(howevr large my delay timer is given) and when the agent replies back to the customer ,an error is shown "OmniListener.js:391 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: globalvariable1 is not defined
    at eval" .Please assist

Comment: Hi ,any update pleaee

Comment: @victor It shouldn't if written like this. What did you write, exactly?

Comment: Exactly as is written in your answer above,no modifications,I tried with various times trying to push in delays,but still it's firing as soon as the welcome message goes from the agent  and displaying the alert,also after the customer replies next,and the agent rereplies that error is showing up

Comment: @victor I just saw your other question, and the comment on that is correct. I had mistakenly put the timeout in the wrong part. See the edited version.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! the time delay is resolved,however the other part is still showing the error and it is not resetting the value to the global variable and throwing this and when the agent replies back to the customer ,an error is shown "OmniListener.js:391 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: globalvariable1 is not defined at eval" ,please can you assist here,I have used this.globalvariable1 too

Comment: @victor Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as a "global" variable, all variables are scoped to at most the component. You'll need to use something like `self.globalvariable1` or `window.globalvariable1` instead.

Comment: I cant thank you enough @sfdcfox, primarily the main crux of the functionality is working fine ,thanks a lot! self.globalvariable worked just fine!,if any thing crops up,I will continue in this thread